# Enable only Monday for each month in Bootstrap Daterangepicker

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

Using the Bootstrap [Daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), I'm trying to enable users to choose only Monday of each month.

```
$('.date-picker input').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true,
        locale: {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
        }
    });
```

this function work only datapicker

```
daysOfWeekDisabled
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".daterangepicker td").not("[data-title$='c1']").addClass("off").removeClass("available");
```

`c1` means monday

you better call this function every time the calendar is **loaded and changed** like `$('.daterangepicker').click( .. )`